# Audio player decides to give up [Flutter] [Audio Cache]

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and I've tried putting together a simple app which plays an audio clip with the press of a button. It works fine for the first maybe 10 - 20 clicks but then gives up.

```
E/MediaPlayerNative(26646): pause called in state 0, mPlayer(0xd2fd3a60)
E/MediaPlayerNative(26646): error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayerNative(26646): Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0xd2fd3a60, mCurrentState=0
E/MediaPlayerNative(26646): error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayer(26646): Error (1,-2147483646)
E/MediaPlayer(26646): Error (-38,0)
E/MediaPlayerNative(26646): error (1, -2147483646)
E/MediaPlayerNative(26646): error (1, -2147483646)
E/MediaPlayer(26646): Error (-38,0)
E/MediaPlayer(26646): Error (1,-2147483646)
E/MediaPlayer(26646): Error (1,-2147483646)
```

`I/chatty  (26646): uid=10093(com.example.soundtest)` identical 1 line

Is repeated a couple of times.

My code:

```
void playSound(String different) {
final player = AudioCache(prefix: "sounds/");
player.play("$different", volume: 1.0);

onPressed: () {
   playSound("up.mp3");
 },

onPressed: () {
   playSound("down.mp3");
 },
```

Comment: It can conflict with other parts of your app. provide them as well so the reader can have a better view of the question.

Comment: Okay, noted. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use LOW_LATANCY.
Like the below code:

```
 final audioPlayer = AudioCache();
 audioPlayer.play("assets/fsdffds.wav",mode: PlayerMode.LOW_LATENCY, volume: 5);
```

......

Comment: LOW_LATENCY doesn't exist for me, is therer anything additional to audioplayers and exoplay that need to be added?

Comment: i use **audioplayers: ^0.16.2**
 try this.

Comment: I fixed the issue by removing a conflicting plugin. Thank you for helping me. Five star rating!